# spring-data-rest HAL base urls in api management platform

Tags: spring-data-rest, hal-json

So i have a spring-data-rest app hosted in heroku:
hotel-app.herokuapp.com

but i want to expose it in an api management platform like mashape.
curl --get --include "https://greekscholar-test-v1.p.mashape.com/" \
  -H "X-Mashape-Key: xPlviBQhz3mshmhlL19hyJjNXJJXp1hm6H5jsn10ZrVHr4n3ZC"

all of the links go back to my original heroku host. how do i configure the links to either just display a relative path, or go to the host of the api management platform?

Answer (score 0):

You need to sign up to mashape and they will map the URL for you.

You should follow this handy guide: http://docs.mashape.com/add-api